# Dynamically changing jQueryUI dialog buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Attempting to change multiple jQuery UI dialog() buttons on the fly.

The problem with below code is that only one button is displayed at the first instance of the dialog(). Two buttons should be displayed.

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/JNssp/):

```
$(function(){
    var dlg = $('#message');

    dlg.dialog({
        autoOpen:false,
        modal:true,
        width: 500,
        close: function() {
            if (seen==0 && ans > 0) {
                cnt++;
                seen++;
                dlg.html('Here is a second message');
                dlg.dialog(
                    'option',
                    'buttons',
                        [{
                            text: 'OK',
                            click: function() {
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                            }
                        }]
                );
                dlg.dialog('open');
            }
        }
    });

    $('#myDiv').hover(
        function() {
            //Hover-in
            if (cnt < 1 || (cnt > 2 && cnt < 4) || (cnt > 5 && cnt < 7)) {

                var msg = 'First display text goes here';
                dlg.html(msg);
                dlg.dialog(
                    'option',
                    'buttons',
                        [{
                            text: 'Download',
                            click: function() {
                                ans++;
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                            },
                            text: 'Not now',
                            click: function() {
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                            }
                        }]
                );
                dlg.dialog('open');
            }
            cnt++;
        },
        function() {
            //Hover-out
            //need this to prevent duplicating hover-in code (double-display dlg)
        }
    );

}); //END document.ready
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have tried to use the `Object` type for the [`buttons`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons) and it works :

```
dlg.dialog(
    'option',
    'buttons', {
        "Download": function () {...},
        "Not now": function () {...}
    }
);
```

See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JNssp/1/)

**Object**: The keys are the button labels and the values are the callbacks for when the associated button is clicked.

EDIT : But you had an error in your array, you must have an array of object and there were missing `{` and `}`.

```
'buttons', [
    {
        text: "Download",
        click: function () {...}
    },
    {
        text: "Not now",
        click: function () {...}
    }
]
```

See [correction of your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JNssp/2/)

Comment: Right you are... and I thought I'd tried everything. Still, [the api documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons) seems to infer that my OP syntax was correct? What's up with that..?

Comment: If you prefer the `array` notation, you must have an `array of objects`, see my edit :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining that. So *that's* what the square brackets were about... Makes sense now. I appreciate the additional example.